# Get caffe intermediate result when calling python from caffe binary lib

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I am using python interface of caffe. In the layer implementation file [softmax_loss_layer.cu](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/softmax_loss_layer.cu), the loss of every single sample in a mini-batch will be summed and divided by the batch size. So the output from the `"softmaxlosslayer"` is the average loss over the mini-batch.

What I want is to get the loss of every single sample which is stored in `*loss_data`, but when I try to use `std::cout` or `fstream`, nothing happened. So I think things turn to be how to get output from c++ binary lib when calling c++ from python.

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

caffe is using [glog](/questions/tagged/glog) library for logging. If you want to output something, you should need to use `glog`'s macros. For example:

```
GLOG(INFO) << "something to be printed";
```

When running your code you need to make sure the environment variable `GLOG_minloglevel` is set to include the log level you want. That is, if you wrote a log with level `INFO`, then you need to set `GLOG_minloglevel=1` (or `0`, but not more than that).

See [this "how to" page](https://download.automotivelinux.org/AGL/mirror/svn/google-breakpad.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/third_party/glog/doc/glog.html) for more information regarding [glog](/questions/tagged/glog) logging.

---

Note: you are trying to get an output from `softmax_loss_layer.cu` code: this code is run on GPU, and therefore you might expect some difficulties with getting output from it. If you are only debugging, you might consider tweaking `softmax_loss_layer.cpp` code instead and run in `CPU` mode: That is, setting `caffe.set_mode_cpu()`

Comment: Thank you so much! Actually, I am trying to get the loss array from the softmax_loss_layer.cu and sort it. Since they don't have function like caffe_gpu_sort, I need to initialize a new array in this .cu file to help sorting. But things don't go well, it always ends up with segment fault (core dumped),  and I think maybe I can't ask for new memory in .cu file. The implementation is quite different between .cpp file and .cu file and the network I am working on should run on gpu.

Comment: @XintingQIU try implementing it on CPU first, to make sure you get what you want. Then move to GPU implementation.

Comment: I am not the root user of the server, so I am working on a custom caffe installed under my account. So I cannot find where the log file is (I know for root user the log files are in /tmp/), and I am using a python interface, I can't set the --log_dir for caffe. @Shai

Comment: @XintingQIU you should be able to set its location by setting the environment variable `GLOG_logdir`

Comment: @XintingQIU alternatively, try logging to stderrand redirect the output yourself